# Filesystem recovery using Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb, data-recovery, ntfs

I have accumulated a number of failed pc's and would like to retrieve all data from them.

They all have some form of Windows and I would like to know whether it is possible to remove their hard drives and install them into a server running Ubuntu from a live-usb or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ubuntu is capable of mounting `NTFS` (and `FAT32`) file-systems by default, so moving your assorted drives into a single machine then booting it from a live-usb will make them accessible.

I'd also advise you to look through the following links in detail as they should help you understand better what you are trying to do:

- [Understanding file systems](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/und_fs.php)
- [6 Ways the Linux File System is Different From the Windows File System](http://www.howtogeek.com/137096/6-ways-the-linux-file-system-is-different-from-the-windows-file-system/?PageSpeed=noscript)
- [Linux: Mount a Windows file system from Linux](http://www.techonthenet.com/linux/mount.php)